# Inconsistent type error Python

Tags: python, typeerror

I am analyzing large text files with a python script. I have the script loop through all of the files in the directory and analyze them individually and put the results in an array. Then export them to a text file in csv format. The results are pure numbers. I have am doing this for 4 different 'vectormodel' objects. My script only breaks on some of them. The error message when it does break is.

```
File "1Vectors.py", line 84, in exportlist

self.vectorlist[i] = (re.sub('[^0-9]', '', self.vectorlist[i])) 

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

The thing is it breaks after the 30th or so file. I would understand this error if it just didnt work, but its breaking very inconsistently. Why would it be breaking randomly. .

Comment: Are you sure `self.vectorlist[i]` is _always_ a string? Could it be `None` or say `int` in some cases?

Comment: I hope you are not modifying the same list in a loop that you are iterating over .. can you provide some more context around that line that triggers the error?

Comment: wow yea you are right sometimes it is an int. When im analyzing it if the result is 0 it doesnt print anything( someone elses analysis script) so i had the default value to int 0 even though im appending string(#s)